# Percentage value to absolute value and vice versa translation causes mismatch due to integer rounding off

Tags: java, math, rounding, percentage, rounding-error

With following operation I translate memory percentage to memory in MB. Percentage memory is calculated with respect to `4096 MB` memory. First lets say `80%` of `4096 MB` memory is needed =>

`4096*.8 = 3,276.8  ~ rounded to 3,276 MB due to integer operation`

Now this 3276 MB value is stored in storage.

Now next time when I fetch this `3276 MB` value from storage and again translate it to percentage memory, I get memory percentage as `79%` due to following calculation and integer rounding off

`3276*100/4096 = 79.98046875 ~ rounded to 79 % due to integer operation`

So there is this percentage mismatch e.g. `80%` to `79%` due to integer rounding off.

How can I avoid this mismatch happening in my java program by correct integer rounding? Is there some generic solution to this problem?

Comment: What about using Math.round(), Math.round(4096 * 80.0 / 100) = 3277 and Math.round(3277 * 100.0 / 4096) = 80

Comment: but will it always ensure correctness? or can there be some corner case while using Math.round?

Comment: in your case with percentages as integers it'll be correct for all the values [0-100]

Comment: Why do you round at all? Why don't you keep the floating point value?

Comment: there is limitation from coding side, existing code is using integers for storage so i can not change that

Comment: Have you considered not storing MB but just B, i.e. the number of bytes?

Comment: in original code "integer" data type variable  is used .......if i use bytes and storage memory is larger e.g. 10GB , then i might get issue due to int upper limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
new BigDecimal( "4096" )
.multiply( new BigDecimal( "0.8" ) )
.setScale( 0 , RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN )
.intValueExact()
```

> 3277

## Rounding with `BigDecimal`

Specify [rounding mode](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/RoundingMode.html) by using `BigDecimal`.

```java
        BigDecimal eightyPercent = new BigDecimal( "0.8" ) ;
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal( "4096" ).multiply( eightyPercent ) ;  
        BigDecimal rounded = bd.setScale( 0 , RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN ) ;  // Bankers rounding.
        int result = rounded.intValueExact() ;  // Throws exception if not fitting into an `int` with no data loss.

        System.out.println( eightyPercent ) ;
        System.out.println( bd ) ;
        System.out.println( rounded ) ;
        System.out.println( result ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/oLjwzi).

You get your desired result of `3277`.

```
0.8
3276.8
3277
3277
```

Answer (score 2):

Any way you round is going to have issues like that, changing rounding strategies is just going to change what cases cause them.  Once you've lost that precision, you can't get it back.  If you want both numbers to be persistent, save both numbers.